# InvalidOperationException ocurred

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

I am trying to access MySql database but get this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The CommandText property has not been properly initialized.

**This Would be my Code**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Login
   Dim cn As New MySqlConnection

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      cn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=pos"
      cn.Open()
      MsgBox("Connected")
   End Sub

   Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
      cn.Close()
      Dim myadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
      Dim sqlquery = "SELECT * from pos.values where username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND password='" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
      Dim mycommand As New MySqlCommand
      mycommand.Connection = cn
      cn.Open()
      myadapter.SelectCommand = mycommand
      Dim mydata As MySqlDataReader
      mydata = mycommand.ExecuteReader
      If mydata.HasRows = 0 Then
         Beep()
         MsgBox(txtUsername.Text & " Invalid")
      Else
         MsgBox("Welcome " & txtUsername.Text)
         MainWindow.Show()
         Me.Hide()
         cn.Close()
      End If
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi Vaughn and welcome to the site! I just made a few little changes to your question to make it more attractive to answerers. (Improved code formatting, removed extraneous code and added problem statement at the top). Hope you don't mind. Don't forget that if anyone answers your question and it solves your problem that you can click on the tick to "Accept" the answer. This helps anyone who comes along later with the same problem. Cheers!

Comment: YOu need to assign your text query to your command - error tells you as much

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error says, you never set the `CommandText` property of the `MySqlCommand` object.  You've defined a `SELECT` query, but never use it anywhere.  Set it on the command object before trying to use that object:

```
mycommand.CommandText = sqlquery
```

---

**Note:** Be aware that your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection attacks**.  You should use query parameters instead of *directly executing user input as code*.  Basically, you're allowing users to execute any code they want on your database.

**Also:** You are storing user passwords in *plain text*.  This is ***grossly irresponsible*** to your users.  If you can read their password, so can an attacker.  User passwords should be obscured with a 1-way hash so that they can *never* be read, not even by you as the system owner.